# Generating certificate for iLO

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, ilo, csr, certbot

I want to generate a proper certificate for iLO web console (iLO is a management engine for HP servers) using letsencrypt. AFAIK there's no way to install private key into iLO, so I've generated CSR from iLO. It contains the following field:

```
Requested Extensions:
    X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
        DNS:ilo.example.com, IP Address:192.168.1.11
```

I've found no way to exclude IP Address part from CSR. I don't need it, I'll use only ilo.example.com. Now I issued

```
certbot certonly --manual --staging --preferred-challenges=dns --csr csr
```

command, completed DNS verification, but got error:

```
An unexpected error occurred:
The request message was malformed :: Error creating new cert :: CSR contains one or more IP address fields
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

AFAIK CSR is signed by private key, so I can't edit it. Can I ask letsencrypt to ignore IP address and issue certificate only for ilo.example.com? Or is there other way?

Comment: I've found a post in HPE forums, that in the future it'll be possible: https://community.hpe.com/t5/Remote-Lights-Out-Mgmt-iLO-2-iLO/Anyway-to-change-the-Subject-Alternative-Name-on-iLo-SSL-Cert/m-p/6952270/highlight/true#M7892 I guess it's not possible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-automatic-certificate-install-on-an-hp-ilo4-management-processor/31038

1. Generate CSR
2. Submit CSR to LE
3. Install resulting cert

Answer (score 1):

Please use **my** [utility](https://github.com/djechelon/letsencrypthpeilo) that deals with CSR generation and DNS challenge (only with GoDaddy here).

The utility requires Powershell and is made by three scripts, of which one is Certbot itself.

1. A script that will request iLO to generate a CSR and download
2. Certbot will request the certificate upon CSR
3. A utility updates GoDaddy DNS to acknowledge DNS challenge

Please note that with HPE iLO it is only possible to perform DNS challenge.

The script I have made leverages the HPE iLO APIs to request the generation of a CSR without the IP address. It worked on two of my servers.

Disclosure. I made the tool and released under MIT License on GitHub